# Convert an array of bounded integers to matrix of bit arrays

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Suppose I have an array `a` of bounded integers (in this case bounded by 5):

```
a = [3 4 4 2 1 5 5];
```

I want to convert this array of integers to a `length(a) x 5` matrix `A` where each row is a bit array with a 1 in the column indexed by the integer from `a`:

```
A = [0 0 1 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 0;
     0 0 0 1 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 1];
```

This is easily accomplished with a `for` loop:

```
n = length(a)
A = zeros(n, max(a(:)));
for k = 1 : n
  A(k, a(k)) = 1;
end
```

I am looking for a vectorized implementation that does not use a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible methods:

1. use `sparse`:

   ```
   A = sparse( 1:n, a, 1, n, max(a(:)) );
   ```

   if you want a non-sparse result

   ```
   full(A);
   ```
2. Using `sun2ind`:

   ```
   A = zeros( n, max(a(:)) );
   A( sub2ind(size(A), 1:n, a ) ) = 1;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and multiple solutions.